How to efficiently draw an invalid Young-Yableaux diagram?
Can we write the LaTeX code to draw an invalid Young-Yableaux diagram in which all rows are not left-aligned? Using the package youngtab and \young()? I want a solution other than using the tizpicture.

Did you click on tag youngtab, or search for it here? What code did you try? What visual result do you expect?

You probably know what you have in mind; unfortunately we don't. Can you add a sketch of the expected output? Even a hand-drawing would be fine. You can also lool at the ytableau package, especially section 4.2 “Skew tablaaux” of the manual.
